# SlideToggle doesn't push content down in Chrome and/or Safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, opera, slidetoggle

I have a site with a hidden div and a link that when clicked, shows the hidden div.

This works great on IE and Firefox on both PC and Mac. However, it doesn't move the content down when clicked on in Safari, Opera and Chrome.

Here's the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function() {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(500);
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".slidingDiv").offset().top + $('window').height()
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be nice if you could post your code on jsfiddle, help us help you:)

Comment: Seems to work for me - http://jsfiddle.net/xYZNV/1/ (Chrome on OSX)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue! It wasn't the JQuery at all, simply the overflow-x on the CSS for the html property.